# How can I use arial narrow in css?

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
#main{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;   
font-family: "Arial Narrow";
position: absolute;
font-size: 10pt;
}
```

this is a part of my css-code, where I want to use arial narrow

Comment: Is this an issue with Firefox? Does it work in Chrome or other browsers?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FftqJ It works fine both on Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Visitors may not have arial narrow. The sample you provided may work on some computers but not all. Arial Narrow has a license that does not allow distribution so you're stuck with hit-or-miss results. Try finding a narrow font on Google Fonts: http://google.com/fonts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use it just like that. The user that views the page has to have the font installed, otherwise the browser will choose a different font.

You may want to specify fallbacks for those who don't have that font, for example:

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a bug with Firefox not recognizing Arial Narrow.

I use the CSS3 "font-stretch" property, and it works fine.

```
body{
font: 13px 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; 
font-stretch: condensed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change like

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work:

```
#main{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;   
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
font-size: 10pt;
}
```

reference it from here: http://cssfontstack.com/

Note: also you must need to download and install that font on server or project where ever you using or you can also give reference to it.